# What genre best fits "Infinity" by LEMMiNO

Tags: identify-this-genre, genre

Which genre of music is LEMMiNO's "Infinity"?

I'm interested in exploring similar types of music.

Answer (score 2):

It belongs to broad genre of Rock/Pop, in a similar vein to Volcano Choir, Angus & Julia Stone, Dorota Miskiewicz and others only with a slightly slower tempo and moody keyboards instead of guitars. Other LEMMiNO tracks such as "Terra" or "Moon" have a certain Vince Clarke/Depeche Mode vibe to them.